# Prosemirror editor tool bar incomplete on Angular 6

Tags: angular6, prose-mirror

I have integrated ProseMirror in my Angular 6 as a text editor using Directives as below:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core'; 
import { ProsemirrorModule } from './prosemirror/prosemirror.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyElementComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ProsemirrorModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  providers: [],

})
export class AppModule {

  }
  ngDoBootstrap() {

  }
}
```

and used html as:

```
<div appEditor></div>
```

all are working well...but toolbar does not appear properly...all aligned one below other  [image: attached screen shot]

No idea how to make it to appear properly. Any help please